# what software, library, framework can I use to do web components?

Tags: javascript, react, angular, vue.js

I have a lot of task with differents technologies, I working with React.js but, the last widtget to insert on my website is "web component"

So this is very useful because a lot of browser supports it.

What software, framework or library is better to do web components?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Web components are reusable client-side elements made using native code or third-party libraries. Web components rely on one or more of these browser features: Custom Element, Shadow DOM, Template, HTML import and ES6 modules. Web component libraries which support Custom Element, Shadow DOM, Template, and ES modules are listed below. <sup>[source](https://www.webcomponents.org/libraries)</sup>

> - [Hybrids](https://github.com/hybridsjs/hybrids) is a UI library for creating web components with simple and functional API. The library
>     uses plain objects and pure functions for defining custom elements,
>     which allow very flexible composition. It provides built-in cache
>     mechanism, template engine based on tagged template literals, and
>     integration with developer tools.
> - [LitElement](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element) uses [lit-html](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html) to render into the
>     element's Shadow DOM and adds API to help manage element properties
>     and attributes. LitElement reacts to changes in properties and renders
>     declaratively using lit-html.
> - [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) is a web component library built by Google, with a simple element creation API. Polymer
>     offers one- and two-way data binding into element templates, and
>     provides shims for better cross-browser performance.
> - [Skate.js](https://skatejs.netlify.com/) is a library built on top of the W3C web component specs that enables you
>     to write functional and performant web components with a very small
>     footprint. Skate is inherently cross-framework compatible. For
>     example, it works seamlessly with - and complements - React and other
>     frameworks.
> - [Slim.js](http://slimjs.com/) is a lightweight web component library that provides extended capabilities for components, such as data
>     binding, using ES6 native class inheritance. This library is focused
>     for providing the developer the ability to write robust and native web
>     components without the hassle of dependencies and an overhead of a
>     framework.
> - [Stencil](https://stenciljs.com/) is an open source compiler that generates standards-compliant web components.